# Setting Styles in tikzset

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I am facing several issues when trying to create a picture as a `tikzset` and load it with different variables.

The tikzset includes styles for:

1. parts of the tikz picture (in the example the nodes) and
2. parts that might be added (in the example the path)

Meanwhile the pictures should be scaled differently, which appears to be an issue with my current code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}  % 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    pics/withscope/.style n args={2}{
        code = { %
            scale=#1,
            mypathstyle/.style={line width=#2mm, ->}, 
            \begin{scope}
                [scale=#1,  
                %mypathstyle/.style would only work here if path inside scope
                every node/.append style={transform shape},
                nodestyle/.style={circle,draw=black,fill=white,thick, font=\bfseries}]
                %nodes 
                \node(1) [nodestyle] {$1$};
                \node(2) [right=of 1] [nodestyle] {$2$};
            \end{scope}
        } %code
    }, % style
    pics/withscope/.default={1}{2}
} %tikzset  


\tikzset{
    pics/thisisscopeless/.style n args={1}{
        code = { %
            %Those wont do anything
            mypathstyle/.style={line width=#1mm, ->}, 
            every node/.append style={transform shape},
            nodestyle/.style wont work

            \node(1) [circle,draw=black,fill=white,thick, font=\bfseries] {$1$};
            \node(2) [right=of 1] [circle,draw=black,fill=white,thick, font=\bfseries] {$2$};
        } %code
    }, % style
    pics/thisisscopeless/.default={1}
} %tikzset


Loading without parameter works\\[2cm]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic {withscope};
\end{tikzpicture} \\

putting everything in tikzpicture works\\

\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=1.5, 
    every node/.append style={transform shape},
    nodestyle/.style={circle,draw=black,fill=white,thick, font=\bfseries},
    mypathstyle/.style={line width=0.2mm, ->}] 
    \node(1) [nodestyle] {$1$};
    \node(2) [right=of 1] [nodestyle] {$2$};
    %path   
    \draw [mypathstyle] (1) -- (2) node[pos=0.5,above] {2};
\end{tikzpicture} \\

scale doesnt work with scope \\

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,mypathstyle/.style={line width=0.5mm, ->}]
    \pic {withscope};
    %   %path   
    \draw [mypathstyle] (1) -- (2) node[pos=0.5,above]  {3};
\end{tikzpicture}   


without scope it works   \\

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,
    every node/.append style={transform shape},
    mypathstyle/.style={line width=0.5mm, ->}]
    \pic {thisisscopeless};
    \draw [mypathstyle] (1) -- (2) node[pos=0.5,above]  {4};
\end{tikzpicture}   

with scope the scale in tkzpicture wont work. You can hand scale through tikzset, but this isnt great\\

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,mypathstyle/.style={line width=0.5mm, ->}]
    \pic {withscope={3,8}};
    %   %path   
    \draw [mypathstyle] (1) -- (2) node[pos=0.5,above]  {5};
\end{tikzpicture}


without mypathstyle in tikzpicture gives an error as "mypathstyle" is unknown\\

\begin{tikzpicture}%[mypathstyle/.style={line width=0.5mm, ->}]
    \pic {withscope={4,8}};
    %   %path   
    \draw [mypathstyle] (1) -- (2) node[pos=0.5,above]  {6};
\end{tikzpicture}   


\end{document}
```

My issues are: If I use `scope` the style works, but `scale` does not. If I don't use `scope` the styles won't work but `scale` does. In both scenarios defining a style for something else outside the tikzset but inside the `tikzpicture` won't work.

I am fairly certain the issue for the last part lies somewhere in the key of the styles i define but i cant figure out how to call it correctly. Does anyone have an idea on how to create a tikzset that difines styles for the tikzpicture it is called in and has also content taht is scaleable through the tikzpicture environment?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. if you say `code={...}`, `...` has to be some code, not something like `key=blabla`. You *can* define keys by using e.g. `\tikzset`, though.
2. If you have `n args=2`, the two arguments have to be passed to the `pic` via `\pic {withscope={3}{8}};` and not `\pic {withscope={3,8}};`

Taking this into account, the MWE becomes

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}  % 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    pics/withscope/.style n args={2}{
        code = { %scale=#1,
            %mypathstyle/.style={line width=#2mm, ->}, 

            \begin{scope}
                [scale=#1,  
                %mypathstyle/.style would only work here if path inside scope
                every node/.append style={transform shape},
                nodestyle/.style={circle,draw=black,fill=white,thick, font=\bfseries}]
                %nodes 
                \node(1) [nodestyle] {$1$};
                \node(2) [right=of 1] [nodestyle] {$2$};
            \end{scope}
        } %code
    }, % style
    pics/withscope/.default={1}{2}
} %tikzset  


\tikzset{
    pics/thisisscopeless/.style n args={1}{
        code = { %

            \tikzset{mypathstyle/.style={line width=#1mm, ->}, 
            every node/.append style={transform shape},}
            %nodestyle/.style wont work

            \node(1) [circle,draw=black,fill=white,thick, font=\bfseries] {$1$};
            \node(2) [right=of 1] [circle,draw=black,fill=white,thick, font=\bfseries] {$2$};
        } %code
    }, % style
    pics/thisisscopeless/.default={1}
} %tikzset


Loading without parameter works\\[2cm]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic {withscope};
\end{tikzpicture} 

putting everything in tikzpicture works

\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=1.5, 
    every node/.append style={transform shape},
    nodestyle/.style={circle,draw=black,fill=white,thick, font=\bfseries},
    mypathstyle/.style={line width=0.2mm, ->}] 
    \node(1) [nodestyle] {$1$};
    \node(2) [right=of 1] [nodestyle] {$2$};
    %path   
    \draw [mypathstyle] (1) -- (2) node[pos=0.5,above] {2};
\end{tikzpicture} 

scale doesn't work with scope \textbf{because the options are local}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,mypathstyle/.style={line width=0.5mm, ->}]
    \pic {withscope};
    %   %path   
    \draw [mypathstyle] (1) -- (2) node[pos=0.5,above]  {3};
\end{tikzpicture}   


without scope it works  

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,
    every node/.append style={transform shape},
    mypathstyle/.style={line width=0.5mm, ->}]
    \pic {thisisscopeless};
    \draw [mypathstyle] (1) -- (2) node[pos=0.5,above]  {4};
\end{tikzpicture}   

with scope the scale in tkzpicture won't work. You can hand scale through
tikzset, but this isnt great.

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,mypathstyle/.style={line width=0.5mm, ->}]
    \pic {withscope={3}{8}}; %corrected syntax for two arguments 
    %   %path   
    \draw [mypathstyle] (1) -- (2) node[pos=0.5,above]  {5};
\end{tikzpicture}


without mypathstyle in tikzpicture gives an error as "mypathstyle" is unknown\\

\begin{tikzpicture}%[mypathstyle/.style={line width=0.5mm, ->}]
    \pic {withscope={4}{8}};%corrected syntax for two arguments 
    %   %path   
    %\draw [mypathstyle] (1) -- (2) node[pos=0.5,above]  {6};
    % doesn't work because mypathstyle is defined in scope
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: *remark :* `every node/.append style=...` can be replaced by the shorter synonym `nodes=...`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue with the 2 arguments. Is it correct to say that the `mypath` would still not be usable outside the `\pic`if defined in the inner `tikzset`?

Comment: @Finn Yes. (One *could* in principle make styles global but this is not at all recommended.)